# Need a qry to join a comma separated column with another table with its Id in it to find the code

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table with

```
Table name TB1
mpeFromWHId mpeToStoreList
8            16,18,24
```

and Table `tb2` are the codes of the comma separated storeid

```
nlid  nlcode
16     ncl
18     mcl
24     dcl
```

I need a query that will result in

```
col1   Col2
8      ncl,mcl,dcl
```

Comment: Could you elaborate your question with a clear example? Use question formatting for better understanding of your question

Comment: Can you fix your data model? You shouldn't be storing comma separated values in the first place.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: agree, but sometimes data model is not in your hands.

Comment: Why did I know that this answer would come? I wonder why the guys creating those horrible models never have to actually use them...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need a function to parse comma delimited string into table, you can use this (found [here])[1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/amitjet/archive/2009/12/11/sql-server-comma-separated-string-to-table.aspx):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].Split1(@input AS Varchar(4000) )
RETURNS
      @Result TABLE(Value BIGINT)
AS
BEGIN
      DECLARE @str VARCHAR(20)
      DECLARE @ind Int

      IF(@input is not null)
      BEGIN
            SET @ind = CharIndex(',',@input)
            WHILE @ind > 0
            BEGIN
                  SET @str = SUBSTRING(@input,1,@ind-1)
                  SET @input = SUBSTRING(@input,@ind+1,LEN(@input)-@ind)
                  INSERT INTO @Result values (@str)
                  SET @ind = CharIndex(',',@input)
            END
            SET @str = @input
            INSERT INTO @Result values (@str)
      END
      RETURN
END
```

Then you can use something like this (but there are many more options off course):

```
declare @searchId int
set @searchId = 8

declare @tb1 table (mpeFromWHId int, mpeToStoreList varchar(100))
insert into @tb1
select 8, '16,18,24'

declare @tb2 table (nlid int, nlcode varchar(30))
insert into @tb2
select 16, 'ncl' union
select 18, 'mcl' union
select 24, 'dcl'

select stuff((
    select ',' + nlcode
    from @tb2
    where nlid in (
        select Value 
        from dbo.Split1((select mpeToStoreList from @tb1 where mpeFromWHId = @searchId))
    )
    order by nlcode
    for xml path(''), type
).value('(./text())[1]','varchar(max)'), 1, 2, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create a user function, you can do like this:

```
;with TB1(mpeFromWHId, mpeToStoreList) AS (
   select 8,'16,18,24'
)
SELECT t.mpeFromWHId,n.ID FROM (
      select *,convert(XML,'<n>'+replace(mpeToStoreList,',','</n><n>')+'</n>') as x from tb1 
) AS t
cross apply(select s.b.value('.','INT') as ID from t.x.nodes('n') s(b)) n
```

```
mpeFromWHId  ID

8   16
8   18
8   24
```